# Show that no two of the spaces $(0,1), \ (0, 1], \ [0,1]$ are homeomorphic.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I want to show that no two of the spaces $(0,1), \ (0, 1], \ [0,1]$ are homeomorphic, with the hint: what happens if you remove a point from each one of these spaces.

No idea where to begin, except that it concludes a chapter on connectedness.

All these spaces are all in the subspace topology of the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

### Edit

(Thanks @Chris Culter)

So far what I've got is:
Let $A = (0,1] - \{1\}$.  If $f:(0,1] \rightarrow (0,1)$ is a homeomorphism, then $f$ restricted to $A$ is a homeorphism onto a subset of $(0,1)$ with one and only one point removed.  But any removal of a point in $(0,1)$ results in a disconnected space, while at the same time $f_A$ ensures that the space is connected, it being a continuous image of a connected space $A$.  Therefore there is no continuous bijective map between the two spaces let alone a homeomorphism.  A similar agument shows that $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$ are not homeomorphic.

I can't seem to show that $(0,1]$ and $[0,1]$ are not homeomorphic using this method though.

Comment: Yes, but I have an answer below checked that doesn't mention cut-points, so obviously there was some stuff left unsaid.

Comment: No, there wasn’t. The answer that you accepted is all about cut-points; it just didn’t use that term.

Comment: They have non-isomorphic orders. The topology is the order topology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, following the hint: if you remove a point from $(0,1)$, is the remaining space connected?

Comment: Okay so if I remove a point from $(0,1]$, namely $1$ then the remaining space is connected but no point can be removed from $(0,1)$ and make the remaining space connected.  But how do I prove that that's a necessary homeomorphism-invariant property?

Comment: Connectedness is defined in terms of the topology of a space, so you could just say that it's "manifestly homeomorphism-invariant". Or, go ahead and prove that any space homeomorphic to a connected space is also connected.

Comment: Please see my edit above.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

All of them have a different number of non-cut-points, i.e. points that you can remove without disconnecting the set.